# Fatal error: Call to a member function findAll() on null in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to get the objects of a repository but I have next error

> Call to a member function findAll() on null

The error line is `$projects = $this->projectRepository->findAll();`

First used the object manager to get the repository, it did not work. The current configuration is:
In Controller

```
/**
 *projectRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDOR\MyExtName\Domain\Repository\ProjectRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $projectRepository = null;
```

And Repository

```
class ProjectRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
  public function createQuery() {
    $query = parent::createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    return $query;
  }
}
```

This happens also with `findByUid($uid)`

The objects exists in DB and visible in BE.

I cleaned the caches, deleted the contents of the typo3temp directory and followed the questions about a similar error (that I thought) `Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object` , but it did not work and the exception I have is different.

I appreciate your help, please guide me to correct this error

Comment: Well that suggests `$this->projectRepository` is not what you think it is. Dump it out and take a look. Assume your logs are showing another error you need to look at. Like your autoloader is failing or you have a typo in the metadata on those c style comments.

Comment: Or simply try to create an instance of your repository like this in your index action: `$test = new \VENDOR\MyExtName\Domain\Repository\ProjectRepository();` and if that fails you'll have more information what's wrong.

Comment: I used `var_dump` for print attribute before use `findAll()` instruction, and saw the correct instance of my repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is almost always caused by the annotation "compiling" of extbase and related to the cache. You said you cleared the caches and removed the contents of typo3temp, but the cache clearing methods are very different and they do not work for every cache.

For example, the annotation cache is only cleared by using the Clear Cache button of the Install Tool. The toolbar icons on top of the TYPO3 backend do not clear these kinds of caches.

The annotation caches will not get stored in the typo3temp folder afaik, but have their own section in the database. Cache clearing should NEVER be done by deleting typo3temp folder content by hand, but ALWAYS via the Install Tool or the appropriate buttons or commands in the TYPO3 backend or the CLI.

Finally, there is an autoload cache of PHP classes, that doesn't get cleared by the Install Tool either. So if you add a new PHP class to your extension in development, you need to deinstall and reinstall your extension via the extensionmanager. If you are using composer to install your TYPO3 instance, it is again a little bit different. If this is the case, you can clear the autoload cache by typing in the command `composer dump-autoload` to clear the class loading cache of composer, since TYPO3 is using it if in composer mode.

I guess that you simply did not try the Install Tool button to clear the cache.

Comment: Thank you, it works with the clear chaches button of Install Tool, but showed me other error of type `Oops` errors, that said `PHP Warning: class_parents(): object or string expected in ....` . I deleted typo3temp content and clear caches since the toolbar on BE of TYPO3 and works all now.

Comment: Now I use other repository of other entity and in the `findAll()` happens again, I clicked only the clean caches since Install Tool and works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

And this error occurs if you forget to inject your repository in your controller:

```
/**
 *projectRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDOR\MyExtName\Domain\Repository\ProjectRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $projectRepository = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the methode __construct, to be careful dont type __constract.